# Convert jQuery $(this) to Raw Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, youtube-api

I am trying to pass in the iFrame object (which is a jQuery element) as a parameter for YT.Player. This unfortunately gives as error as YT.Player is expecting a raw element. I am wondering how would I be able to convert `$(this)` to a raw element.

```
$('iframe.ytplayer').each( function() {
    players[id] = new YT.Player( $(this), {
        events: {
            'onReady': onReady,
            'onStateChange': onStateChange
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: What about just ... `this`?

Comment: What do you think `this` is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`this` is the raw element all by itself in a jQuery `.each()` iteration.

```
$('iframe.ytplayer').each( function() {
    players[id] = new YT.Player(this, {
        events: {
            'onReady': onReady,
            'onStateChange': onStateChange
        }
    });
});
```